# I can not send consecutive data from the serial port

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I want to send consecutive data from the serial port. But serial port is not taking the second data after the first data is sent. If I stop and restart it, it works fine. This is my code:

```cpp
String inputString="";
boolean stringComplete=false;

void serialEvent() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    char inChar=(char) Serial.read();
    inputString+=inChar;
    if(inChar=='\n') {
      stringComplete=true;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  inputString.reserve(200);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if(stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);
    inputString="";
    stringComplete=false;
  }
  if(inputString=="HELLO") {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    serialEvent();
  } else if(inputString=="WORD") {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    serialEvent();
  }
}
```

For circuits and simulation:
https://tinkercad.com/things/6fTYYBc3w0e

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think, it's must be C++.

Comment: actually it looks more like Java. there is no 'boolean' in c/c++ and no String  as well. They exists in java though,

Comment: I think this is Java. Please specify the language correctly.

Comment: It's no longer not contain any language information.

Comment: @Serge It's not Java it's Arduino's C++.

Comment: @gre_gor thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings while the inputString is set to an empty string before it can be used.
Put the string compares inside the if(stringInput) block. Also, you'll need to include the newline character in the comparison.

```
void loop() 
{
   serialEvent();

   if(stringComplete)
   {
        Serial.println(inputString);
        if(inputString=="HELLO\n")
        {
           digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
           serialEvent();
        }
        else if(inputString=="WORD\n")
        {
           digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
           serialEvent();
        }

        inputString="";
        stringComplete=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: I try this. I got two lights on. I understand that: '/n' is not working. If I write  if(inChar=="O") {stringComplete=true} program is running.

Comment: It's '\n' not '/n'.. Also check what the actual end of line character is. Could be \r, \r\n or \n depending on system, settings, terminal program etc.

Comment: I typed wrong. I meant to say '\n' already not working. The same things are true for  \r, \r\n. Thanks.

Comment: I'd try to debug and send all received characters back as number value to the serial port. Then use an ascii chart to find out what the actual last character you check on is, then check for that value instead of a character.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. I was a little late but thank you.